# How to format integer data source without comma then put star before and after the column in crystal reports?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have order id column and i need to put star before and after the integer value , but first i need to remove comma in crystal reports what i did :

1- insert text box and write **

2- insert the order id column from the table

3- formar the object and keep it without comma (1122) format

4- when I need to drag and drop the order id field between the ** its not accept .

5- How can I insert * before and * after the integer and after format the number.

6- order id value by default like this example :

2,000,000,180

I need to remove the comma and keep it like this

2000000180

then add star before and after`*2000000180*`

and read always from database order id value .

NOTE :

I can drag and drop the integer order id column direct from field explorer to the text box between the stars but if i drop the column in the work area section I cannot then put it between the atars .

How to solve this issue and put stars after format the object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- In crystal reports Right click formula field then select New .

2- Type the name of your formula.

3- Type the following code under crystal syntax :

```
stringvar replaceid := Replace("2,000,000,180",",",""); 
stringvar Result := "*" + replaceid + "*"
```

4- Replace command and this syntax will remove the comma .

5- The result will be  `*2000000180*`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the string.Rplace() method in order to remove the ',' and than string.format to add *.

```
string orderId = "111,222,333,444";
string cleanId = string.Replace(",","");
string text = string.Format("*{0}*", cleanId);
```

*Note* that if you are using c# 8 and above you can use string interpolation instead of string.Format.

```
string text = $"*{cleanId}*";
```

Comment: I  need to use this code in crystal syntax after creating formula field but string not accepted I think using stringvar will work , and string.Replace not working and show error a number , currency , amount , boolean date time or string is expected here (on string)

Comment: Sorry but the code I wrote is pure c#, I am not to familiar with crystal-reports so I think @abdullah answer might be more suited to your problem.